# How to change parameters set in parameters.yml in imported parameters.php in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, config, symfony-3.4

I have a database password I'd like to dynamically retrieve and have PHP code to retrieve that.

Currently my parameters.yml.dist looks like

```
parameters:
    database_user: bob
    database_password: ~
    database_host: alice.training.database
imports:
    - { resource: 'parameters.php' }
```

Parameters.php looks like

```
<?php
    $container->setParameter('database_password', functionCall());
```

But this does not update the value.  I noticed that if I print the database_user variable using getParameter then I get a `FileLoaderException` of `You have requested a non-existent parameter 'database_password'`.

Comment: What if you erase database_password from the yml ?

Comment: You cannot modify the container after it's been compiled.

Comment: You still can do something like he's trying to do : https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/configuration/external_parameters.html

Comment: @FTW I guess it has some semblance, but that's not what I'd call 'dynamic', he wants to execute php code to retrieve the value. _Maybe_ you could abuse a custom `EnvProcessor` but it's certainly a hack and probably not useful for what he wants since it'll run very early.

Answer (score 1):

File parameters.yml.dist stored initial parameters. But code trying to take from file parameters.yml
You need just copy file parameters.yml.dist to parameters.yml and edit it (if needs).